¿Cómo insertar un registro desde un archivo PHP en el hosting 000webhost?
Trato de insertar un registro a la base de datos desde un archivo PHP en el hosting 000webhost, pero no me realiza el registro, no reconoce la instrucción INSERT, al hacerlo en el localhost de XAMPP desde mi computadora, si me permite y el sistema funciona perfectamente, pero en el hosting de 000webhost no reconoce esta instrucción.
Este es el códdigo como tengo para realizar el registro:
Es el formulario y las instrucciones para insertar el registro, todo desde el mismo archivo:
    <header class="header">
        <h2>
            Carretera: Alazán - Canoas
        </h2>
        <h3>
            Km. 0+000 al 156+300
        </h3>
        <h3>
            Obras Complementarias de drenaje
        </h3>
    </header>

    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['agregar'])){
            $idcomplementarias = null;
            $kminicialc = $_POST['kminicialc'];
            $kmfinalc = $_POST['kmfinalc'];
            $lado = $_POST['lado'];
            $tipodeobrac = $_POST['tipodeobrac'];
            $caracteristicas = $_POST['caracteristicas'];
            $estadofisicoc = $_POST['estadofisicoc'];

            include('db.php');
            $con = connection();
            $sql = "INSERT INTO complementariasac() VALUES('$idcomplementarias', '$kminicialc', '$kmfinalc', '$lado', '$tipodeobrac', '$caracteristicas', '$estadofisicoc')";
            $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

            if($query){
                echo "<script languaje='JavaScript'>
                alert('Registro guardado correctamente');
                location.assign('complementariasAC.php');
                </script>";
            }else{
                echo "<script languaje='JavaScript'>
                alert('ERROR: El registro no se guardo');
                location.assign('complementariasAC.php');
                </script>";
            }
            mysqli_close($con);

        }else{
    ?>

    <div class="conceptos">
        <h4>Obras Complementarias de drenaje</h4>
        <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST">
            <label>Km.inicial:</label>
            <input type="number" min="0.0" max="156.3" step="any" name="kminicialc" placeholder="Km inicial" required>
            <label>Km. final:</label>
            <input type="number" min="0.0" max="156.3" step="any" name="kmfinalc" placeholder="Km final" required>
            <label>Lado:</label>
            <select id="lado" name="lado">
                <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
                <option value="Derecho">Derecho</option>
                <option value="Izquierdo">Izquierdo</option>
            </select><br><br>
            <label>Tipo de obra:</label>
            <select id="tipodeobrac" name="tipodeobrac">
                <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
                <option value="C">C.</option>
                <option value="T">T.</option>
                <option value="B">B.</option>
            </select><br><br>
            <label>Características:</label>
            <input type="text" name="caracteristicas" placeholder="Características" required><br><br>
            <label>Estado físico:</label>
            <select id="estadofisicoc" name="estadofisicoc">
                <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
                <option value="Bueno">Bueno</option>
                <option value="Regular">Regular</option>
                <option value="Malo">Malo</option>
            </select><br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="agregar" value="Agregar registro"><br><br>
        </form>
        <form action="complementariasAC.php" method="POST">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Regegresar a Obras Complementarias de Drenaje">
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
</div>

Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar.
Gracias

Hola, entendemos que no funciona... pero necesitamos conocer un poco mas... da algun error o ocurre algo mas???

Tengo la sensación, porque ya lo he visto antes, de que se trata tan solo de las rutas relativas, generalmente sucede cuando tratas de replicar lo que tienes en tu pc pero en el servidor de hosting las rutas no son las mismas.
